# Burned Windows 7 DVD won't boot

Tags: windows-7, bootable-media

An interstate colleague copied the contents of a Windows 7 install disc onto the network, and I copied the network files to my desktop.

I burned the files onto a blank DVD, as they appear on the original DVD.

However, a laptop won't boot from this DVD. The extension bay is set to boot before the HDD.

When I press F11 during startup, I receive a message saying "BOOTMGR is missing". The file "bootmgr" is present on the DVD, in the root directory.

Why won't the burned DVD boot?

Comment: By copying contents do you mean. He went copy/paste from the dvd to a folder or did he create an image(iso) of dvd?

Comment: @TimWilliams: He copied/pasted from DVD to a folder.

Comment: Then you have a DVD of files, not a DVD which can be executed. It's not an image.

Comment: @Dave: can I convert the files to an ISO image?

Comment: I found Magic ISO (paid) and [ISO Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iso-creator-cs/) (free)

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft for where to get an official iso you can make a bootable installer from

Answer (score 11):

The boot file wasn't added. Much like OS installations hide the bootloader in the first sectors of the hard drive, the installation discs use a hidden boot file. Without that file there is NO way to make the disc bootable. The boot file is located in the /boot folder of the directory you downloaded. You will need to use a program like IMGBurn, or PowerISO that support manually adding a boot file, to make a disc bootable.

In which-ever program you decide to use you will need to use the add boot file option, and browse to /boot/etfsboot.com, that is the file you need.

If you'd like you can get an installation disc from here: https://superuser.com/a/305434/383497 this would be much less work.